# Laravel 5.6 - How to run job or event with parameters from command line?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have an `App\Jobs\BanUser` job which accepts a parameter `id` to block a bad user by passing their id. That works perfectly if called from a controller like this:

```
dispatch(new BanUser($id));
```

But when I try to do that from the tinker command line with the full namespace like this:

```
dispatch(new App\Jobs\BanUser('1'));
```

I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/Jobs/BanUser' not found in Psy Shell code
>   on line 1

Any idea how to accomplish this job with the passed `id` parameter from the command line?

NOTE: If the solution requires starting up a queue from command line just for this job, maybe it's best to set it as an event? I don't want it to queue, just want to be able to run it in real time by passing parameter and executing the `BanUser` respective code from command line for either job or event.

Comment: try `dispatch(new \App\Jobs\BanUser('1'));`

Comment: same result with the leading \

Comment: and if you type `>>> use App\Jobs\BanUser;` and then `>>> dispatch(new BanUser('1'));`?

Comment: nope.. still returns same error.

Comment: Make sure you have `App\Jobs` namespace in your `BanUser` class file.

Comment: @podvzbzdnul you're right, my mistake, it was nested in an additional folder which was not part of the namespace. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you so much for this simple reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have correct namespace `App\Jobs` in your `BanUser` class.

Also check `BanUser` class file is placed in right directory.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
app('Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher')->dispatch(new App\Jobs\BanUser('1'));
```

I am not sure if it will work but, you can give it a try.

Comment: This also helped dispatch the job right away, I just had the namespace incorrect, upvoted!

Comment: By the way, this works for short: Bus::dispatch(new App\Jobs\BanUser('1'));